# leader stats not loading

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a clicker game and I need a multiplier value in the leaderstats. it all works until I add the data stores and it stops displaying the multiplier, but the clicks are still being displayed.
Here is my code:

```
local DSS = game:GetService("DataStoreService")

local ClicksStore = DSS:GetDataStore("ClicksStore")
local MultiStore = DSS:GetDataStore("MultiStore")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    
    local stats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    stats.Name = "leaderstats"
    
    local clicks = Instance.new("IntValue", stats)
    clicks.Name = "Clicks"
    clicks.Value = ClicksStore:GetAsync(player.UserId.."--clicks") or 0
    
    local multi = Instance.new("IntValue", stats)
    multi.Name = "Multiplier"
    multi.Value = MultiStore:GetAsync(player.UserId.."--multi") or 1
    
    
    game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function()
        ClicksStore:SetAsync(clicks.Value, player.UserId.."--clicks")
        MultiStore:SetAsync(multi.Value, player.UserId.."--multi")
    end)
    
    while true do
        wait(300)
        ClicksStore:SetAsync(clicks.Value, player.UserId.."--clicks")
        MultiStore:SetAsync(multi.Value, player.UserId.."--multi")
    end
    
end)
```

Heres a screenshot
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE88z.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have the key and values backwards in your calls to `SetAsync`. See the [docs](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/GlobalDataStore#SetAsync).

```lua
    local clicksKey = player.UserId.."--clicks"
    local multiKey = player.UserId.."--multi"

    game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function()
        ClicksStore:SetAsync(clicksKey, clicks.Value)
        MultiStore:SetAsync(multiKey, multi.Value)
    end)
    
    while true do
        wait(300)
        ClicksStore:SetAsync(clicksKey, clicks.Value)
        MultiStore:SetAsync(multiKey, multi.Value)
    end
```

Comment: ok, thank you but the stat itself isn't showing

Comment: Hmm that is weird. Sorry my answer didn't help.

Comment: were good i figured it out! but thank you!